# Get Specific Tags from Multiple Similar Tags of XML

Tags: xml, shell, awk, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file of the format:

```
<classes>

 <subject>
  <name>Operating System</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory</type>
  <faculty>Prof. XYZ</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject>
  <name>Web Development</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Lab</type>
 </subject>

</classes>
```

I want to get the result of only those classes which are of 'type' = 'Theory' **using Shell Script**.

I tried using :

`awk -F'[<>]' '/<name>|<credit>|<type>|<faculty>/{print $3}' file.xml`

But this command is returning every field of the xml tags.

i.e.

```
Operating System
3
Theory
Prof. XYZ
Web Development
3
Lab
```

Looking for the solution to get only specific tag values if multiple tags are present.

TIA.

Comment: What do you want to output? Just the name? The name, credit, type, and faculty?

Comment: All the tag details i.e. name, credit, type, faculty where the subject tag has inner tag as faculty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, I am not an expert of `xamlstarlet` giving it a try here.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v  "classes" Input_file |
awk '
NF{
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
  print
}'
```

***Brief explanation:*** Processing xml file with `xmlstarlet` then for output formatting I am using `awk`(after xml processing) which removes unnecessary spaces and new lines from output.

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP told he can't install `xmlstarlet` in system so adding `awk` solution but fair warning `awk` is NOT tool for xml following solution been added by seeing shown samples only.

```
awk -F"[><]" '
/<\/subject>/{
  if(found){
    print val
  }
  found=val=""
  next
}
/<subject>/{
  found=1
  next
}
found{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$3
}
'   Input_file
```